How to make an API call to check wether a user is valid or not on every component rendering in react?
I have a user authentication app, once a user logs in I save his data on the redux store and use it to manage the authenticated state through redux. But this never gave real-time data. Say, that the user got blocked in the middle of his session. There were no options to log him out unless he visited a protected route in the server.
So I created a custom hook to make API calls to the server to validate the user. The problem is I created a protected route component and wrapped all the routes in this component. I expected to make the API call when he switched from component to component. But still, the Protected route is the parent and there were no state changes happening there. So the API call is not made every time he visits a component.
One way I could do this is by invoking this hook in every component which the user visits. But that's not an efficient approach. How can I make the API call whenever a child component is changed? Or this there any other method were I can acquire this functionality?
This is my Route structure:
<Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
    <Route element={<DashboardHeader />}>
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
        <Route path="classroom/:classroom_id" element={<ClassroomLayout />}>
            <Route
                path="summary"
                element={<ClassroomSummary />}
                errorElement={<Error />} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Route>

//Protected Route were the hook useAuth call is made. Hook is working perfectly fine!
const ProtectedRoutes: React.FC<DashboardProps> = () => {
    const role = useRole();
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const { loading, user, error } = useAuth(role);

    if (loading) return null
    if (error) navigate('/');

    return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/' />
}


In case you missed it or haven't taken the full [tour] yet (You earn a badge BTW!) there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after someone answers that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Create a separate layout route component that listens for the location to change and runs an effect each time.
Example:
import {
  Outlet,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
} from "react-router-dom";

const AuthCheckLayout = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    // location path changed, run side-effect to check
    // user authentication status
    
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      // handle any App auth state cleanup and navigate home/login
      ...
      navigate("/login", { replace: true });
    }
  }, [pathname]);

  return <Outlet />;
};

Wrap all the routes you want to track the user's auth status in in this AuthCheckLayout layout route component, which allows the ProtectedRoutes layout route component to protect specific sets of routes.
Example:
<Routes>
  {/* Check user auth status on these routes */}
  <Route element={<AuthCheckLayout />}>
    ...

    <Route element={<DashboardHeader />}>
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />

      {/* Protect classroom routes */}
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
        <Route path="classroom/:classroom_id" element={<ClassroomLayout />}>
          <Route
            path="summary"
            element={<ClassroomSummary />}
            errorElement={<Error />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Route>

      ...

    </Route>

    ...

  </Route>
</Routes>


Thanks... Is this location refferes to the components? Since the  useEffect hook is depended on location, whenever the location changes the API  call will be made. Is this how it is working?

@AhammedZulaikh Yes, that is the gist. When the location changes, the effect would be to check the user's auth status.

@AhammedZulaikh Very welcome, happy to help. Cheers and good luck!
